# php: uploading file while recording path in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm still a beginner in php and i'm having an issue on this particular problem, i've checked a few of the olders posts, but didn't find what i need.

So this code is supposed to connect to the database, upload a file from a form, create a smaller copy of the file(a picture), and then record in the database a few info from the form and the path of the newly created picture.
Everything works fine until the recording, variables can be seen through print_r but won't record...

The code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_newprojet'])){

$bdd = Connection::getInstance('localhost', 'website', 'utf8', 'root', '');
$man = new Admin_manager($bdd);
$titre = $_POST['nom_projet'];
$date_proj = $_POST['date_projet'];
$text = "<pre>".htmlentities($_POST['presentation'])."</pre>";
$name = $_FILES['photo']['name'];

//create destination folder
$titre_dossier = str_replace(" ","_",$titre);
$dir_proj = "../projets/".$titre_dossier;
if(!is_dir($dir_proj))
    @mkdir("$dir_proj", 0777, true);
$dir_proj_orig = "../projets/$titre_dossier/original/";
if(!is_dir($dir_proj_orig))
    @mkdir("$dir_proj_orig", 0777, true);

//uploading picture
$nom_orig = $dir_proj_orig.$name;
$envoi = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $nom_orig);
if($envoi){

//creating a gd library based smaller copy of picture
    $photo = $man->createBlock($nom_orig, $titre);
    //this one works as well, I let it there in case its presence in itself would be my problem, the new picture goes in $dir_proj

 //recording database
    $photo_dir = substr($dir_proj,3)."/";
    $req= $bdd->exec("INSERT INTO projet VALUES ('', '$titre', '$date_proj', '$text', '$photo_dir')");}}
```

And here is the concerned table if needed( i used a varchar for the date since i only keep the year):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projet` (`id_projet` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`nom_projet` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,`date_projet` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,`presentation` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,`photo_presentation` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id_projet`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Thanks for those who'll take the time to help me

Comment: do you have any errors?can you copy it here? did you tried to print the insert statement and execute it on phpmyadmin?

Comment: In the insert replace the '' with null to get the auto_increment value. Additionally, it would not hurt if you had sql exception handling after you execute any sql statements to confirm if they were executed correctly and see the actual error message if they were not.

Comment: well thanks, i had no error statement, and using a singleton i didn't manage to put a setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); on the PDO object, it seems it was due to my $text, a few characters weren't accepted, i used $text = "<pre>".htmlentities($_POST['presentation'])."</pre>"; were there a better way to accept any kind of character?

Comment: please check the htmlentities properties http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp

Comment: Thanks ClaudioM i was missing an ENT_QUOTES.

Answer (score -1):

use this code .............this work fine ....

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "infiniti";
$dbname = "mywok";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$titre = 'xxx';
$date_proj = '2015-09-12';
$text='your content';
$photo_dir = '.../dir/dir';
$sql = "INSERT INTO projet VALUES ('', '$titre', '$date_proj', '$text', '$photo_dir')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Why should the OP switch to mysqli? Passing empty string to generate next auto increment value may not work, depending on configuration settings (no_auto_value_on_zero).

Comment: Thanks for the help, as i sais my problem was in the syntax of the $text, being french i have lots of accents here and there, therefore the htmlentities, but it didn't work well with mysql, so if anyone had a suggestion.